# Ssh without password shows error?

Tags: debian, openssh

I have two debian machine virtual box running 
Debian GNU/Linux 9. I have tried using the following process but I still 
get the password asked for? It fails and it says - Postponed publickey for test from 10.21.12.74 port 45962 ssh2 [preauth]

They have 
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7, OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019

One client machine I generated the default SSH key pairs
- public and private.

```
$ssh-keygen
```

Next, I did -

```
ssh-copy-id test@10.21.12.49

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'test@10.21.12.49'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

The sshd server says -

```
debug1: trying public key file /home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: matching key found: file /home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 1 RSA SHA256:VvQDLGFJdfO9FUOqa1ODV6iLT4Te0Nm5Bz1OUA57LjY
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key 0x564e7bdd0c70 is allowed
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 23
debug3: send packet: type 60 [preauth]
debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg ssh-rsa [preauth]
Postponed publickey for test from 10.21.12.74 port 45962 ssh2 [preauth]
```

The ssh client says -

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:VvQDLGFJdfO9FUOqa1ODV6iLT4Te0Nm5Bz1OUA57LjY
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:VvQDLGFJdfO9FUOqa1ODV6iLT4Te0Nm5Bz1OUA57LjY
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
debug1: Trying private key: /home/test/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/test/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/test/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/test/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/test/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/test/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
test@10.21.12.49's password:
```

It worked by killing ssh-agent in the client using

## ssh-agent -k

and next I need to reboot the machine. Is there any good way?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, you have this parameter:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Also would be nice to check the system logs if you have SELinux activated.

Answer (score 0):

If your `/etc/X11/Xsession.options` includes the line `use-ssh-agent`, the GUI session will automatically include a `ssh-agent` process even if you did not specifically set it up.

The SSH client will by default prefer using the agent if it's available, so having the agent present but with no keys configured to it (using `ssh-add`) and/or without a functioning `ssh-askpass` GUI dialog tool may be causing your problems. If that's the case, and you wish to use the agent, use `ssh-add` to add the key to the agent before using it; if you don't want to use it at all, remove the `use-ssh-agent` line from the Xsession.options file and login again.

If you just want to avoid the agent in a single script or terminal session, you could just unset the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable.